# Software to read KCacheGrind files on Mac

Tags: osx, php, profiling

I'm looking for [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/) alternative software which will read and analyse PHP application profile data.

The features should include:

- reading trace files generated by XDebug (`xdebug.auto_trace`/`xdebug.profiler_enable`)
- should support new [Subposition Compression](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-format.html#cl-format.overview.compression2) format
- compatible with the recent OS X (El Capitan)

It would be great if it's free of charge, but premium apps with reasonable price are also considered.

Comment: Yupp, much better. I'll reopen it now – please also add whether it must be free or how much money you're willing to spend :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some alternatives:

- [WebGrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind)
- [qcachegrind](https://gist.github.com/justfalter/1029580) (`brew install qcachegrind`); See: [installation steps on OS X](https://langui.sh/2011/06/16/how-to-install-qcachegrind-kcachegrind-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard/).
- [XHProf: A Hierarchical Profiler for PHP](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) (`pecl install xhprof`)
- [MCG](http://mcg-app.com/) premium app can analyse your application profile data natively on your Mac (released to the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mcg/id799178412?ls=1&mt=12)). This is newer version of [MacCallGrind](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33552/maccallgrind).

  [image: Screenshots of MCG app - xdebug - analyse your application profile]

  <sup>Image: [Homepage of MCG](http://mcg-app.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another premium alternative is [ProfilingViewer](http://profilingviewer.com/), available on the Mac App Store.
Can display the data as Treemap, Call graph, Heatmap, Call tree, can hide system functions and has a source file viewer annotated with the costs. Handles multiple types of costs. Can print PDF Reports. It can combine multiple metrics into one chart.

[image: Profilig Viewer, Callgraph]